# Is it possible to use Amazon Cognito groups to set permissions on AW resources such as Amazon DynamoDB and Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-dynamodb

In my application I want to users to be able to create an organization i.e. (OrgA) and then have users sign up under said organization using either an invite code or token. Users in OrgA should have access to an Amazon S3 directory (which stores images and files) and access to a database table that has been created for the said organization.

I could not find a solution on how to implement this online and was wondering if using  Amazon Cognito groups was a good idea to meet requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported by the Amazon Cognito Service. That is, you can use Amazon Cognito to control permissions for different user groups in your app. This ensures that users have appropriate access to backend resources, determined by the group they belong to. For more information, see [Building fine-grained authorization using Amazon Cognito User Pools groups](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/).